# Solving $(x^{y+1}x\ln x - x^2 y^x)y' = y^{x+2}\ln y - x^y y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had the differential equation $$(x^{y+1}x\ln x - x^2 y^x)y' = y^{x+2}\ln y - x^y y^2$$
 and simplified it to

$$x(xx^y(y'\ln x)+yx^y (yx^{-1})))+y(yy^x(\ln y)+xy^x(xy^{-1}y'))=0$$

But what to do next ? Any hints?

Comment: i think a numerical way is the best idea

Comment: Is this an exercise or an actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MrYouMath A friend gave it to me. I'm not sure from where he got it from.